# How do I create an 2-D array in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, multidimensional-array, functional-programming

I'm trying to learn Haskell by creating a board game. I currently have a game that is [[Char]] and I'm trying to create another board of the same columns and rows filled with the character "a". How do I go about doing so? Also can you explain how storing a value and accessing would work?

Comment: In general, the [`array`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/array-0.5.1.1) package is what you want. As a beginner, just stick to nested lists.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This is a worthwhile question, but we generally expect that some own effort to solve the problem is shown.

Answer (score 4):

Rather than *creating a new board the same size but with different content*, it may be helpful to think of this operation as *replacing the content of an existing board*. Of course, because Haskell is an immutable language, it amounts to the same thing - the only way to change something is to produce a new version of it - but it should help you to see that this is fundamentally a *mapping* operation.

```
replaceWithA :: [[a]] -> [[Char]]
replaceWithA xss = map (map (const 'a')) xss
-- or, point-free:
replaceWithA = map (map (const 'a'))
-- or, as a list comprehension:
replaceValues xss = [['a' | x <- xs] | xs <- xss]
```

---

If you wanna go deep you can get the compiler to write this code for you. The `Functor` type class generalises `map` to structures that aren't simple lists:

```
class Functor f where
    fmap :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

In what sense does this generalise `map`? If you replace `f` with `[]` you can see that `fmap` has the same signature as `map`:

```
fmap :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
```

Indeed, this is how `[]`'s `Functor` instance is implemented:

```
instance Functor [] where
    fmap = map
```

Anyway, GHC knows how to write `Functor` instances all by itself. I'm going to define a `newtype` wrapper for 2D lists and utter the magic words *`deriving Functor`!*

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor #-}
import Data.Functor

newtype TwoDimensional a = TwoDimensional { getTwoDimensional :: [[a]] } deriving Functor
```

The generated `fmap` will have the following signature:

```
fmap :: (a -> b) -> TwoDimensional a -> TwoDimensional b
```

Now you can use a standard bit of machinery for replacing elements with a fixed value:

```
replaceWithA :: TwoDimensional a -> TwoDimensional Char
replaceWithA = ('a' <$)
```

As you gain experience with Haskell and its standard abstractions like `Functor` you'll get better at spotting when a given operation is an instance of a more general pattern. Setting up your types carefully allows you to delegate lots of boilerplate to the compiler, allowing you to tersely and declaratively solve the interesting part of your problem.